# How to print what’s returned in a flask route in react native

Tags: python, react-native, flask

I have a project about runnning an ML model in react native using flask and getting the predictions to the React Native app.

Right now, I have this code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/predict/<valueOne>,<valueTwo>')
def predict(valueOne, valueTwo):

    prediction = model.predict([[valueOne, valueTwo]])
    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return 'Sales should be $ {}'.format(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And if I go to my browser and run `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict/2,3`, it will look like this:

[image: Results of running flask]

I'd like to print the value (650.0) on my react native console. I tried using `fetch` but that didn't work. How can I do this?

Edit:
This is what I tried with fetch:

```
console.log(fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict/2,3'))
```

The output is:

```
Promise {
    "_40": 0,
    "_55": null,
    "_65": 0,
    "_72": null,
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors with fetch ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan hey, umm I'm not getting any error, but I don't know how to get the value using fetch and one of my friends told me that you can only use fetch to retrieve a json array, was he right?

Comment: No you can retrieve anything check this answer on getting a string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427386/using-fetch-to-get-a-simple-string

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan yes, I just tried it out and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have had experience with this. If you're not already, you need to make an axios request and change state. It should look something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

constructor(props){
 
 this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(api_url_card)
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({ data : data });
    });
}
```

The above console.log of the axios request will print the data coming through from the request. However, this code should also help you save in state. Hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: You can also add error handling in the request if you wish.